# Server doesn't listen Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm getting Server Doesn't Listen error every time I try to connect to my ubuntu server. I have checked all the conf files. Changed postgresql.conf file
`listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432`
 and pg_hba.conf file
`host    all             all             xxx.xx.xxx.0/24         trust`

but still no success.

Comment: Just to check the network, did you tried to telnet on db port from yout client?

Comment: theres no problem with the network. I checked my network status.

Comment: Sorry for all the trouble it was a really silly mistake, solved it downing by firewall.